# iOS Swift 3 Keep TableView content at the right position when keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a Viewcontroller with a ContainerView and a TextField (looks like your typical chat app). Inside the ContainerView is an embedded TableView. I have implemented an observer function to increase the bottom layout constraint of the TextField, making the TextField and the ContainerView move up with the Keyboard.

The problem is the offset / inset of the TableView. It looks like the keyboard hides the TableView.

How can i make the content of the tableView move with the containerView?

Here i have added some Screenshots:

[image: This is the Chat]

This is the initial Chat View Controller.

[image: This is the Chat after the keyboard shows up]

Now when the Keyboard shows up, the TableView does not maintain its scroll position. It might look like the containerView is simply behind the Keyboard, but it actually adjusted the size.

[image: scroll indicator shows that the inset/offset is wrong]

Now when you scroll down, you see that the tableView does not maintain its scroll position.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the observer UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame and change the contentOffset of the tableView.

Here's how it's done.

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self
        , selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame)
        , name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame
        , object: nil)
```

and here's the keyboardWillChangeFrame function

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification) {
    let beginFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let delta = (endFrame.origin.y - beginFrame.origin.y)
    self.threadTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.threadTableView.contentOffset.y - delta)
    bottomConstraint.constant = view.bounds.height - endFrame.origin.y
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I also got the idea regarding this with this article.
http://derpturkey.com/maintain-uitableview-scroll-position-with-keyboard-expansion/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can set the `tableView` `contentInset` to keyboard's height when the keyboard is shown and set it to 0 when keyboard is hidden.

You can do it using keyboard notifications : **UIKeyboardWillShow, UIKeyboardWillHide**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

func keyboardWasShown(_ notification : Notification)
    {
        let info = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo
        let value = info?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
        if let rawFrame = (value as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        {
            let keyboardFrame = self.contentTableView.convert(rawFrame, from: nil)
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height
            var contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets
            contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0)

            self.contentTableView.contentInset = contentInsets
            self.contentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification : Notification)
    {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.contentTableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.contentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but it seems like the inset is not the problem. If i use your solution it does only move the inset up very far. I got a better result setting the offset.y about +80. I hope there is a solution to this :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you update the [`contentInset`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619406-contentinset) property on the table view to account for the keyboard height in the observer function you've implemented?

Alternatively could you update the bottom constraint of the ContainerView to account for the keyboard height?

Comment: If i update the contentInset i get a big gap at the bottom when trying to scroll down, and it does not move the content of the tableview up. I tried setting a constraint for the containerView bottom, same results.